# Review Menu not Updating

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, top-bar

Since the new UI, I've noticed this issue - only with the **Low Quality Posts** menu item:

[image]

Even though this queue is empty, the menu indicates review needed.

Anyone else?

> Version: 48.0.2685.52 (PGO) - Opera is up to date
>    Update stream:   Stable
>    System:  Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: How many items did you just review? Was it at least 5?

Comment: No, only the one that was in the queue. And it's cleared now, but it stayed for several reloads and other reviews over ~10 minutes.

Comment: This happened to me last night, also in connection with the Low Quality Posts queue. I reviewed the one item that was in the queue, but the red alert button persisted afterward.

Comment: I think it's not a bug. Aren't the visual icons based on the total number of items in the queue for all people? While the "queue has been cleared" message occurs after you get through your *personal* queue (which excludes items that you have chosen to skip). This happens to me often because I skip many items in review.

Comment: Also, caching issues, perhaps. I clicked the red dot, reviewed until it's empty. I do not see the red dot now.

Comment: [Threshold is currently set at 5 for LQ review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly); that's probably too low. The kicker here is that it's 5 tasks in queue, *not* 5 tasks that you can review - so if there are 6 in queue and you've reviewed all of them, you'll still see the indicator at least once per hour until some of them get reviewed, but won't be able to review anything until new tasks get added. We'll review these thresholds shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be considerably less likely now (still possible, but less likely to occur on a regular basis).

[Jon and I put together a system of rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly) for determining the thresholds at which these indicators are displayed, which we'll be applying on a regular basis (to this and other sites). The critical issue for the LQ queue is that it generally takes 2-3 reviewers per task to dequeue - that's likely to cause tasks to stay in the queue long enough to light up the indicator twice (it cannot light up more than once per hour for each individual). So ideally, we set the threshold just high enough that it usually takes more than an hour to build up the required number of tasks - this then gives more reviewers time to process them when it appears, as some portion of them will be completed each time the indicator draws more reviewers in.

Comment: The same phenomenon that Davo talked about above is happening again on my machine right now: the red indicator circle for Low Quality Posts is showing, but when I click that review queu, I get the message "This queue has been cleared! If you're looking for more to review, view all review queues." This isn't the message I get when, for example, I've used up my daily quota of close/leave open votes in the Close Vote queue—nor does the red indicator circle show up in the drop-down review queue summary box next to Close Votes when I've used up my votes for the day, even if other items are there.

Comment: Hmm... I can't see why that happened at the time you posted this, @Sven; there would appear to have been plenty of items in the queue that you hadn't yet reviewed. The only thing that occurs to me is that perhaps several other people all jumped on them at that moment and essentially locked them for a few minutes; have you seen this again since?

Comment: No—but I'll let you know if it happens again. In both instances, the queue in question has been the Low Quality Posts queue. I'll pay close attention to my exact steps the next time I review that queue, in case the phenomenon recurs.

Comment: Happening to me - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ0Tp.png